# BigQuery SQL to keep the difference between two date values as 7 days

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, sql-date-functions

I have 2 date parameters in my BigQuery, one is for the first time open date(first_open) and other is the date when values are fetched(date). I need to find the set of users(id) who have opened on a specific date and their values for ONLY the next 7 days not more.

Eg.

1June20(first_open) user should be only in the date till 7June20(date)

2June20(first_open) user should be only till 8June20(date)

7June20(first_open) user should be only till 13June20(date)

```
SELECT
  event_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) uniques,
  COUNT(id) as total
FROM
  `x-12.analytics_7.xyz`
WHERE
  (first_open between "2020-06-01" and "2020-06-07") 
  AND (date BETWEEN "20200601" AND "20200613")
  AND event_names in ("app_open","first_open")
  AND platform = "ANDROID"     

GROUP BY
  event_names
```

As you can see from the query I'm using I'm restricting the users to 7 days of open but I can't restrict their values to only 7 days.

Comment: Your dates appear to have different formats.  Are they stored as `date`s?

Comment: No. first_open is extracted from timestamp in micros. Extract (DATE FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS( user_first_touch_timestamp )) AS first_open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe, you can use `COUNTIF()`:

```
SELECT event_name, COUNT(DISTINCT id) uniques, COUNT(id) as total,
       COUNTIF(date <= DATE_ADD(first_open, interval 7 day))
FROM `x-12.analytics_7.xyz`
WHERE first_open between '2020-06-01' and '2020-06-07' and
      date BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-13- and
      event_names in ('app_open', 'first_open') and
      platform = 'ANDROID'   
GROUP BY event_names;
```

Or, you can put the logic in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE first_open between '2020-06-01' and '2020-06-07' and
      date >= first_open and
      date < date_add(first_open, interval 7 day) and
      event_names in ('app_open', 'first_open') and
      platform = 'ANDROID'
```